# Convert $map and $arrayToObject aggregation query using morphia java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, morphia

I have this aggregation query. How can i rewrite this query using morphia java ?

```
aggregate(
[{
    $project: {
        items: {
            $map: {
                input: "$items",
                "in": {
                    "k": "$$this.key",
                    "v": "$$this.value"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        items: {
            $arrayToObject: "$items"
        }
    }
}])
```

Any answers will be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I dont know about morphia java. Is that possible to use mongoTemplate in Morphia java?

Comment: No I don't think so